# Error: For frame [Laser]: Frame does not exist

Tags: rviz, laser, ros-melodic, turtlebot, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!,

I am trying to build a map using `roslaunch turtlebot3_slam turtlebot3_slam.launch slam_methods:=gmapping` on a turtlebot3. Unfortunately I have issues with the LIDAR.

I wrote my own publisher following the tutorial  [Publishing Sensor Streams Over ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors), to see if gmapping works with "fake" data.
However I am getting the error **"Fixed Frame [laser] does not exist"** both with this method and running `roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch` (I am using a RPLIDAR instead of the stock LIDAR coming with the turtlebot) . I cannot upload a file since I do not have enough points.

Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324549/error:-for-frame-%5Blaser%5D:-frame-does-not-exist/) by [vincent_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/41971/vincent_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-03**:\

> I cannot upload a file since I do not have enough points.

what would you want to show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error indicates that even though your `LaserScan` messages are being received (by "a" consumer, you don't tell us which), there are no TF transform broadcasts to backup the `laser` frame that has been specified as value for `frame_id` in your messages (in the [Header](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)).

You'll have to make sure that you either:

1. use a `static_transform_broadcaster` to provide a transform between *something* and `laser`
2. use a URDF with a `link` named `laser` to the scene with a `joint`
3. make the `laser` frame the root of everything

if you already have a turtlebot URDF, I would suggest to use either option 1 or 2, preferably option 2.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/41971/vincent_m/) on 2019-06-10**:
Thank you, your 2. suggestion worked!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
I saw this in the previous response you posted:

> Our consumer should be rviz, as we are trying to build in map there.

pedantic, but important: RViz is just a simulator. It does not do any mapping, nor is it involved in the process, other than letting you observe the progress that some other node(s) publish.

So although RViz is "a consumer" of the data, and it does need a correct TF tree, it only needs it to be able to visualise your sensor data for you.